# MYSQL/PHP table design for friends table/query to select friends

Tags: mysql, database-design

For a social network site, I have a table with the ids of the inviter and the invitee and the status of the invitation ie accepted or not.  According to what I've read, this seems to be best practice for a friends table.

Table friends

```
id | inviterid |inviteeid |status
```

however, for a given userid, I want to display all the "friends" the person has including their names. I can get a list of records of relationships with a simple query

```
Select * from friends WHERE inviterid = '33' or inviteeid = '33'"
```

But, this does not translate easily into a list of friends, since the friends could be either inviters or invitees so the field will be different depending on who invited whom.

Is there a better table design for a friends table?  Alternatively, is there a sql syntax that would select friends who can be either inviters and invitees.  Ultimately, I need to do a join to another table that has the users names.

Answer (score 0):

You have a user table with below colums

```
userId|name|...
```

and your friend table

```
id | inviterid |inviteeid |status
```

if you want to find friends of a user that this user invited themes you can use below query!

```
select id, status from friend_tbl inner join user_tbl on user_tbl.id=friend_tbl.inviterid;
```

or if you want to get friend of this user that themes invitee his/her you can use below query:

```
select id, status from friend_tbl inner join user_tbl on user_tbl.id=friend_tbl.inviteeid;
```

I hope these can help you and i can understand your purpose!

Answer (score 0):

Use union to get two kinds of friendS together, then you can join the results with username table.

```
Select inviterid as friend_id, status from friends where inviteeid = 33
Union
Select inviteeid as friend_id, status from friends where inviterid =33
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally would just prefer to have two tables for this case, friend table and invite table

Friend Table

```
id | userid | friendid
```

So for selecting friends would be just

```
SELECT friendid FROM friend_table WHERE userid = 33
```

Invite Table

```
id | inviterid | inviteeid | status
```

For changing the status of invite table once the user approves, and insert new row to friend table

```
UPDATE invite_table SET status = 'accepted' WHERE inviterid = 33
INSERT INTO friend_table (`userid`, `friendid`) VALUES (33, $friendid)
```